# Durandal page loading lifecycle doesn't seem to be doing what I'd expect it to

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have a simple page that is part of a SPA I'm doing.  Whilst this page loads, I want to display a "please wait, loading results..." message.  Simple, huh?  Nope...

My resultspage html is just:

```
<section>
    <div data-bind="with: project">
        <h3 class="page-title">Results</h3>

        <div>
            <div data-bind="visible: $parent.session.isBusy()">
                <p data-bind="text: $parent.loadingtext"></p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: !$parent.session.isBusy()">
                <p data-bind="text: $parent.loadingText"></p>
                Total Energy: <span data-bind="text: total_Energy"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The above page is loaded into my "shell.html" page in a fairly normal way - into the "content" section:

```
    <section>
        <!--<section id="content" class="main"> -->
        <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
        <!--</section>-->
    </section>
```

My resultspage viewmodel (simplified) is:

```
        var getStarted = function () {
                session.isBusy(true);
                return datacontext.calcResults(session.prjID())
                    .then(function () {
                        return datacontext.getProjectById(session.prjID(), project)
                            .then(function () {
                                session.isBusy(false);
                            });
                    })
            }};

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            project: project,
            session: session,
            loadingText: loadingText,
            binding: function () {
                system.log('Lifecycle : binding : labTool');
            },
            bindingComplete: function () {
                system.log('Lifecycle : bindingComplete : labTool');
            },
            attached: function (view, parent) {
                system.log('Lifecycle : attached : labTool');
            },
            compositionComplete: function (view) {
                getStarted();
                system.log('Lifecycle : compositionComplete : labTool');
            },
            detached: function (view) {
                system.log('Lifecycle : detached : labTool');
            }

        };

        return vm;
```

The problem is that all the page navigation stuff loads up and display (the bit above my content section in shell.html) but the html in my resultspage never shows up until AFTER the "getStarted" method is complete, which is completely opposite to the desired behaviour.

I want the message to display whilst loading and then disappear when complete and the other fields are bound.  I've experimented with `attached`, `compositionComplete` and several other events but nothing seems to work and the html doesn't show up whilst the "getStarted" method is running.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here?  My "busy" spinner elsewhere in shell.html works fine. Is it something to do with the way I'm composing the view into the content section?

Activate function:

```
        var activate = function () {
            loadingText('Loading, please wait...');
        };
```

Comment: You aren't showing your activate function so it is almost impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Activate is irrelevant in this case though, surely?  Anyhow, have added it to original post...

Comment: That's a trivial statement - it's only irrelevant if you aren't doing anything in activate, which if you aren't showing it we would have no way of knowing.  Also you don't mention which version of Durandal you are using so it is impossible to decide whether it is irrelevant or not.

Comment: OK, I apologize :-)  Durandal 2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem as it appears to me is that you are binding the section to the project using the `with: project` binding but inside of it you are trying to display text that only appears while loading, but you will never see that text until after the project loads, at which point you no longer *need* that text because it is already loaded.  Consider this to see if I am right -

```
<section>
    <div data-bind="with: project">
        <h3 class="page-title">Results</h3>

        <div>
            <div data-bind="visible: $parent.session.isBusy()">
                <p data-bind="text: $parent.loadingtext"></p>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: !$parent.session.isBusy()">
                <p data-bind="text: $parent.loadingText"></p>
                Total Energy: <span data-bind="text: total_Energy"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: session.isBusy()">
        <p data-bind="text: $parent.loadingtext"></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Remember that the `with` binding is almost the same as the `if` binding except that it sets the context.

Comment: Oh for god's sake, why do I always make such stupid bloody errors when I put together these questions so carefully!?  I only added that in when I copied in some other code and never even considered I was messing up the binding context... Of course it was exactly that... as project didn't exist until after I did my `getStarted` call then my "loadingText" didn't even get looked at.  Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for taking the time to answer my daft question. Hopefully someone else may stumble over this one day and learn from my stupidity!